# Is it logical to prove 2 conditions imply an equation by showing that the equation and one condition necessitate the other condition?

Tags: logic

If we have a proposition like "For all x in {Z}, there exists a y in {Z}, such that [some equation] is True"

The normal approach is to substitute x and y into the equation and prove the equation holds.

It is also possible to rearrange the equation until you define y in terms of x, then show that this definition satisfies y in {Z}. Does this approach to proving a proposition have any logical holes, are there any propositions where doing it "backwards" would give you an incorrect Truth value.

I'm relatively confident that this approach is equivalent to a proof by construction but I'm not 100% sure it always holds and is logically sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works, **if the rearranging is done such that the original and 'rearranged' equation are equivalent**.

So for example

$$\forall x \in \mathbb Z\; \exists y \in \mathbb Z: x+y=17$$

can be proved by rearranging the equation equivalently to $y = 17-x$ and then if $ x \in \mathbb Z$ then also $y  \in \mathbb Z$.

As a counterexample, consider the statment

$$\forall x \in \mathbb Z\; \exists y \in \mathbb Z: \sqrt{x+y}=-3.$$

One can rearrange the equation, by squaring, to $x+y=9$ and finally to $y=9-x$, but squaring is not an equivalence transformation, you may gain additional solutions that weren't there before, which is exactly what happens here.

In complicated examples, it may not be so obvious where the "mistake" (non-equivalent transformation) is. If you have to evaluate/understand such a proof, you have 2 options.

1. Put in the value of $y$ given in the rearranged equation into the original equation, and simplify. Remember that for example $\sqrt{t^2}$ equals $|t|$, not necessarily $t$, where $t$ is some term.
2. Check the rearrangement sequence for any transformation that is not necessarily equivalent (like squaring). Makes sure it is equivalent, by for example checking that both sides of an equation being squared have the same sign.

Comment: This is a really useful response and exactly what i was looking for. I suspected as much but wasn't sure if there was some hole in assuming the last thing and proving an intermediate step. Will mark as answered now!